# Split and pure exact sequence of sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a topological space and 
$$\varepsilon \ :\ 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$
be an exact sequence of sheaves of ${\cal O}_X$-modules. $\varepsilon$ is said to be pure if 
for each point $x\in X$, the induced sequence 
$$0\to A_x \to B_x \to C_x \to 0$$ is pure as a sequence of ${\cal O}_{X,x}$-modules.

Is it true to say that any split exact sequence of ${\cal O}_X$-modules is pure?

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the definitions?

Comment: Tensor products commute with direct sums, and if the sequence is split, $B \cong A \oplus C$.

Comment: A short exact sequence of modules is pure iff it is a filtered colimit of split ones.